# laravel delete multiple record from different database at once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want delete two record  from different table with one delete function. however it is only deleting one of the record even though I passed two different Ids. 
this is my delete function

```
 public function delete($id){
   $user_id = auth() ->user()->id;
   $card =  Card::where('id', $id)->delete();
   $actCity = city::where('id', $id)->delete();

  return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Post Removed');
```

this is my delete button

```
 @if (!empty($cardd && $actCity))
   {!!Form::open(['action'=>['PlanController@delete','id' =>$cardd[0], 'id'=>$actCity[0]],'method'=>'POST','class'=>''])!!}
   @endif
    {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
    {!! Form::submit('Delete', array(
        'class'   => 'btn btn-danger',
        'onclick' => "if( ! confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your 
 package?')){return false;}"
    )) !!}  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

my route

```
Route::delete('delete/{id}', 'PlanController@delete');
```

Comment: you can not use same `id` as a parameter for more than once. You should use `id` and `city_id` in your route like `Route::delete('delete/{id}/{city_id}', 'PlanController@delete');` and use at other places like wise

Comment: You mean I need to change the column name

Comment: check my answer,i have added as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use same parameter name more than once,
Do something like this :

```
 public function delete($id, $city_id){
   $user_id = auth() ->user()->id;
   $card =  Card::where('id', $id)->delete();
   $actCity = city::where('id', $city_id)->delete();

  return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Post Removed');
```

this is my delete button

```
 @if (!empty($cardd && $actCity))
   {!!Form::open(['route'=>['PlanController@delete','id' =>$cardd[0], 'city_id'=>$actCity[0]],'method'=>'POST','class'=>''])!!}
   @endif
    {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
    {!! Form::submit('Delete', array(
        'class'   => 'btn btn-danger',
        'onclick' => "if( ! confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your 
 package?')){return false;}"
    )) !!}  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

my route

```
Route::delete('delete/{id}/{city_id}', 'PlanController@delete');
```

Comment: can you check in `delete` function by doing `dd($id, $city_id)`. Is it getting correct ids for your tables ?

Comment: are you using soft deletes?